# Function Returning Number instead of team?

Tags: r, function

My main goal is to create odds based off of the team score and return a "simulated" winner. But whenever I do the winner(Blue_Jays, Mariners) it returns [1] 100, which is the correct value for the Blue Jays, but I want it to return the team name.

```
Blue_Jays <- 100
Mariners <- 64
winner(Blue_Jays, Mariners)
winner <- function(team_one, team_two) {
  team_one_score <- team_one / (team_one + team_two)
  team_two_score <- team_two / (team_one + team_two)
  winner_score <- runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
  if (team_one_score > team_two_score & winner_score <= team_one_score) {
      winner <- team_one}
  if (team_one_score > team_two_score & winner_score >= team_one_score) {
    winner <- team_two}
  if (team_two_score > team_one_score & winner_score <= team_two_score) {
    winner <- team_two}
  if (team_two_score > team_one_score & winner_score >= team_two_score) {
    winner <- team_one}
  if (team_one_score == team_two_score & winner_score >= team_two_score) {
    winner <- team_one}
  if (team_one_score == team_two_score & winner_score >= team_one_score) {
    winner <- team_two}
  return(winner)
  }
```

Comment: I think(not sure) this could be better solved with `merge`s/lookup tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the name of the team using `deparse` and `substitute`.

```
winner <- function(team_one, team_two) {

   team_name1 <- deparse(substitute(team_one))
   team_name2 <- deparse(substitute(team_two))
   team_one_score <- team_one / (team_one + team_two)
   team_two_score <- team_two / (team_one + team_two)
   winner_score <- runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)

   if (team_one_score > team_two_score & winner_score <= team_one_score)
          winner <- team_name1
   if (team_one_score > team_two_score & winner_score >= team_one_score) 
           winner <- team_name2
   if (team_two_score > team_one_score & winner_score <= team_two_score) 
           winner <- team_name2
   if (team_two_score > team_one_score & winner_score >= team_two_score) 
           winner <- team_name1
   if (team_one_score == team_two_score & winner_score >= team_two_score) 
           winner <- team_name1
   if (team_one_score == team_two_score & winner_score >= team_one_score) 
           winner <- team_name2
   return(winner)
}

set.seed(213)
Blue_Jays <- 100
Mariners <- 64
winner(Blue_Jays, Mariners)
#[1] "Blue_Jays"
```

It might be possible to simplify/remove some `if` conditions.